# Proof of convergence and its proper notation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, notation

While evaluating the limits of sequences and writing down their proofs, I almost never get full points, despite the "actual" proof being correct. The mistakes are solely concerning notation.

For example, consider the sequence 
$$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}= (-1)^n+2$$

The task is to find all the accumulation points of the sequence and find all the accumulation points of the set  $ \{x_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Now despite this being painfully obvious, I would create two subsequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n-1}$ and show that they converge to 3 and 1 respectively. Is there any need to show that $(-1)^n$ converges to 1 for even integers $ n \in \mathbb{N} $?

Secondly, I'd claim that if $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty }{x_{2n}}=3$ that I know that $ \{x_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ has an accumulation point at 3. I'd do it in the same way for 1. This follows from the fact that for a certain $n_0$ every member of the sequence is in the epsilon neighborhood of the limit, which is 3. And that is the very definition of accumulation points of sets.

**What other things need to be said in order for this to become a proper proof?**

Comment: For example, not $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} = (-1)^n + 2$ but : $x_n = (-1)^n + 2$, for every $n$. $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a *set*, while $(-1)^n + 2$ is a *number*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbf N}$ is the image of a function $x\colon \mathbf N \to \mathbf R$ (and hence a set) where you define $x(n)=:x_n$ for all $n\in \mathbf N$.

The notation $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}= (-1)^n+2$ is not good even if I think that everybody will understand what you want.

Your ideas are *okay*. First consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbf N}$ with $x_n = (-1)^n +2$. $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbf N}$ is not convergent since we can pick the subsequences $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbf N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbf N}$ with $a_n=x_{2n}$ and $b_{2n+1}$ and see/show that $a_n\to 3$ (since we have $a_n=3$ for all $n\in \mathbf N$) and $b_n \to 1$. Therefore $1$ and $3$ are limit points of $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbf N}$.

In my opinion you have finally to show that these are the only limit points. (This can be easily shown by contradiction.)